# using the $app object inside a controller (Lumen)

Tags: lumen

Ok im farly new to lumen and laravel and im trying to make this api https://packagist.org/packages/codenexus/lumen-geoip work in lumen, i installed it via composer and im able to use it and obtain locations based on the IP given when im inside the routes.php

But when i'm using the same code inside a controller its doesnt let me proceed cause the $app variable is not defined.

This is the code that works inside the routes

```
    $app->geoip->getLocation('148.210.21.180')->country->names['en']
```

I have been reading that the service container could help me in this solution but i feel lost... 
Thanks in advice for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$app` variable is not available inside your controllers, but you may use the `app()` method anywhere in your code to access the application object.

So, try this in your controller:

```
app()->geoip->getLocation('148.210.21.180')->country->names['en']
```